# Mongo db geo near not working in laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, mongodb-query, latitude-longitude

I am using Laravel 5 with mongo Db database. I have used jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package for all mongo related functions. Everything is working fine.

But when i tried geonear as per information provide on this link([Geo near query link][1]) of mongodb. I works fine. I used following query to get distance between all records of my collection.

Command:-

```
({ geoNear: "sale_event",
   near: { 
      type: "Point", 
      coordinates: [ 76.7171945,30.7291196 ] 
      }, 
   spherical: true, 
})
```

this query is working fine in command prompt and giving me the distance with result :-

```
{
 "results" : [
  {
   "dis" : 0,
   "obj" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("568e01fc04896fcd208b4575"),
    "seller_rating" : "4.5",
    "latLong" : [
     76.7171945,
     30.7291196
    ],
    "description" : "Where'd",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-01-07T06:13:16.152Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2016-01-07T06:13:16.150Z")
   }
  },
  {
   "dis" : 244708.75191385587,
   "obj" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("568e01eb04896fcd208b4574"),
    "seller_rating" : "4.5",
    "latLong" : [
     77.0999578,
     28.5561624
    ],
    "description" : "Where'd",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-01-07T06:12:59.263Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2016-01-07T06:12:59.261Z")
   }
  }
 ],
 "stats" : {
  "nscanned" : 20,
  "objectsLoaded" : 2,
  "avgDistance" : 122354.37595692794,
  "maxDistance" : 244708.75191385587,
  "time" : 3
 },
 "ok" : 1
}
```

But when i used same  command in laravel it is not giving me the same result :-

I have added following method to run the same command.

```
$r = DB::command(array( 'geoNear' => "sale_events",
  'near' => array( 'type' => "Point", 'coordinates' => array('76.7171945','30.7291196')), 'spherical' => true ));
```

It giving me following result :-

```
Array
(
    [ok] => 0
    [errmsg] => can't find ns
)
```

Please help me how can i get the distance in laravel according to the latitude and longitude with mongodb in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a new database instance. This query works quite well on Laravel 5:

```
$mongodb = \DB::getMongoDB();

    $lat = 3.1416;
    $lng = -99.99999;

    $near = $mongodb->command(array( 
        'geoNear' => "sale_events", 
        'near' => array( 
            'type' => "Point", 
            'coordinates' => array(
                $lng,
                $lat
                )
            ), 
        'spherical' => true, 
        'maxDistance' => 2500 ));
```